# session attribute removal from jsp

Tags: jsp, taglib

Is it possible to call taglib to remove the attribute on certain object events like `onClick()` etc because right now these are getting called when the page is getting loaded,I don't want this to happen as the user has to be able to see a report which will require a attribute as well the page where page where is navigates to before the report is beeen presented is the one where this attribute needs to be removed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can issue an ajax-request `onclick`, and then, in a servlet, you can call `session.remove()`.